# How to display selected date in a label

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have this below code where i want whenever i will select start and end date and click on + sign, it should add it in a label below and display.

How to achieve this -

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="ReservationController" sidebar="false" applyBodyTag="false" standardStylesheets="true" id="page">


<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>


     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>    

   <script>
        function testFunction() {

alert(document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.form.datepicker}'));

    </script>
<apex:form id="form">    
<!--input type="text" id="datepicker"/-->

<apex:inputField value="{!positionreserv.Start_Date__c}"  id="datepicker" style="width:auto;display: inline-block;"  html-placeholder="Start Date" />

<apex:commandButton value="Test" onclick="testFunction(); return false;"/>

<p id="demo"></p>
</apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: post your ReservationController and how have you declared the positionreserv ? Does positionreserv have a getter/setter?

Comment: yes its an getter setter. Reservation__c positionreserv  = new Reservation__c ();

Comment: can you post the controller

Comment: Posted...........

Comment: I have updated my code.. When i am using input tag, i am able to get the alert of selected date..The same is not happening for apex:inputfield